# Idea for create cornered textview with different colors in android

Tags: android, background, textview

I am stuck. In layout I add from code TextViews. I have list of elements and I add TextViews depend of elements from list. This is works fine. Now, I have a problem because this textviews should have cornered background with different colors, depends of name. So I have defined 6 colors in

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="colors">        
        <item>#ff0000</item>
        <item>#00ff00</item>  
        <item>#0000ff</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

When I use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >         
   <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="@color/common_border_color" />

   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

   <padding
           android:left="1dp"
           android:right="1dp"
           android:top="1dp" />

   <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

for background I can't change colors. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the background of your `TextView` is a `shape`, you can change the background or border of it by

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable)textView.getBackground();
gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));      // change the background color of your TextView to red
gradientDrawable.setStroke(20, Color.parseColor("#0000ff")); // change the border of your TextView to blue, 20 is the width of the border
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want. But you can try code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:centerColor="#ff0000"
                android:endColor="#00ff00"
                android:startColor="#0000ff"
                android:type="linear" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" android:right="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#aaaaaa" />
        </shape>
        </item>
</layer-list>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I want to add textviews from code for example 5 textviews. Every textview should have rounded background and different color of this background. For example: first textview have yellow background, second red background etc. All background should be rounded